# A palavra "uber", no sentido de transporte alternativo, tem plural?

Tags: estrangeirismos, número-gramatical

Ouvi hoje, em uma estação de rádio que toca noticias, uma repórter relatar que "do lado de fora, vários taxis e úberes aguardavam...", o que soou muito estranho aos meus ouvidos. A pergunta então é: o substantivo uber, no sentido de modelo de transporte alternativo, já é considerado uma palavra da língua portuguesa?  Pode também ser usado para referir-se ao veículo automotor em si?  Neste caso, é variável em número?

Comment: O dicionário infopédia tinha nas "palavras novas" o verbete [uberização](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/uberiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o). É um verbo, mas o substantivo ainda não se encontra lexicalizado...

Comment: Isso não é um caso de [metonímia](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/o-que-e/portugues/o-que-e-metonimia.htm)? Já que provavelmente a expressão também incluía carros e motoristas que trabalham em outras plataformas, sem ser a Uber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que a flexão no plural de *uber* (considerando que o substantivo é usado mesmo sem estar nos dicionários) é por simples acrescente de um **-s**, portanto:

> uber -> uber**s**

A razão é palavras estrangeiras terminadas em **-n** que não estejam já "naturalizadas" na língua poderem fazer o plural sem o acrescento da vogal epentética, por exemplo:

> slogan -> slogan**s**
>
> soutien -> soutien**s**
>
> amén -> amén**s**

Os casos acima são raros. Não os devemos confundir com plurais que terminam em **-ns** mas em que o singular terminam em **-m**. A maioria dos estrangeirismos quando são adaptados à escrita/pronúncia portuguesa sofrem alterações gráficas mais extensas, por exemplo:

> [Shilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling) -> Xeli**m** -> Xeli**ns**
>
> vilebrequin (ver a origem etimológica no dicionário) -> [berbequi**m**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/berbequim) -> berbequi**ns**

---

---

Na citação do texto:

> taxis e **úberes** aguardavam..."

*úber*-***es*** segue a regra normal da ortografia para flexão em número das palavras que no singular terminam com as consoantes ***-n, -r, e -z***; é introduzida uma vogal [epentética](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ep%C3%AAntese) entre o radical e o sufixo *"-s"* do plural. É o mesmo para:

- abdómen -> abdómen-***es***
- amor -> amor-***es***
- variz -> variz-***es***

> o substantivo uber (...) já é considerado uma palavra da língua portuguesa?

É um neologismo e estrangeirismo, sendo o nome de uma empresa pode usar-se mas a dicionarística (de forma sábia) é resistente a cristalizar a palavra como verbete no dicionário porque as empresas facilmente podem mudar de nome por qualquer motivo o que levaria o termo a cair imediatamente em desuso. É o teste do tempo a um termo que pode ser transitório. (Fiquei surpreso por descobrir que [úbere](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%BAbere) existe e é um termo da anatomia.)

Em Portugal o termo geral mais correcto seria [TVDE](https://www.imt-ip.pt/sites/IMTT/Portugues/TransportesRodoviarios/TVDE/Paginas/TVDE.aspx) que é a sigla da expressão legal *"**T**ransporte Individual e Remunerado de Passageiros em **V**eículos **D**escaracterizados a partir de Plataforma **E**letrónica"*. **Uber** é de facto também usado como sinônimo para o conceito, mas -para além de a uber poder mudar de nome- existem outras empresas concorrentes. Por agora não é certo que uber se venha a cristalizar no vocabulário como foi o caso de *Xerox-ing* ou *Hoover-ing* no inglês.

> Neste caso, é variável em número?

É sim, ao seguir a regra geral da morfologia (e ortografia) causa menos estranheza aos falantes porque os paradigmas de flexão são aplicados pelos falantes de forma intuitiva.

Para ser uma palavra que não admitisse flexão em número teria de terminar em -x (como *"o toráx"* -> *"os toráx"*) ou ser usada como [nome não contável](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/nomes-contaveis-e-nao-contaveis-o-caso-de-alimentacao/35572) o que não é o caso na frase exemplo.