# A palavra "nerd", e sua derivada "nerdice", já são consideradas vocábulos da língua portuguesa?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, estrangeirismos, gíria

A palavra "nerd" é muito usada no Brasil e seu significado é conhecido pela maioria dos falantes de pt-BR.  Tenho ouvido mais recentemente o termo "nerdice", como uma qualidade característica dos "nerds".
A minha pergunta é a seguinte: qual o status atual de ambas as palavras em pt-PT e pt-Br?  Gíria? Palavras ainda não incorporadas à língua? Linguagem informal ?  Sei que do outro lado do Atlântico, nossos amigos tentam evitar estrangerismos (o que é louvável) e quase sempre criam uma palavra nova, como por exemplo o "rato" ao invés de mouse e "esferovite" ao invés de isopor. Há em pt-PT palavras novas com o significado de "nerd" ou "nerdice"?

[**Nerd**](https://www.google.com/search?q=nerd+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&sxsrf=APwXEddRpFKYrr_bXcGBNXZ3QZ_BWZD6mQ%3A1685226078575&ei=XoJyZI_mIoac5OUPwOy84Ac&oq=nerd+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgUIABCABDIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBAgAEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjoHCCMQsAMQJzoKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoHCAAQDRCABDoGCAAQHhANOggIABAIEB4QDUoECEEYAFDTB1iID2DDHWgBcAF4AIABhQGIAYADkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBwAEByAEF&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) - Que ou quem tem comportamento considerado pouco social e parece interessar-se geralmente apenas por assuntos técnicos ou científicos.

[**Nerdice**](https://www.google.com/search?q=nerdice+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&oq=ner&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l2j69i64j69i57j0i67i650l2j0i10i512j46i10i131i199i433i465i512.4147j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - Conduta comportamental intrigantemente peculiar de um Nerd. Modo de pensar, expor ou agir de forma inteligentemente diferenciada do convencional, mas que nem sempre tem efeitos positivos.

Comment: O dicionário brasileiro Houaiss e o dicionário português Infopédia têm *nerdice*. Quase todos os outros dicionários que eu vi tinha *nerd*

Comment: O estatuto é palavra estrangeira de uso informal segundo o priberam. Ou seja, não se vai ver a palavra escrita na norma culta. Se dissermos entre jovens sabe-se o sentido, mas a palavra também pode soar mal e não ser tolerada pelas outras pessoas.

Comment: A expressão mais próxima no centro de Portugal seria: *"cromo dos computadores"* sendo que no priberam *cromo* é definido como: *" pessoa que tem um comportamento considerado estranho, excêntrico ou ridículo."* A alternativa seria dizer entusiasta ou profissional dos computadores.

Comment: @bad_coder Note que nerd é usado muito mais amplamente que para computadores apenas.

Comment: @stafusa pois é, o par nerd/geek em que [geek](https://dicionario.priberam.org/geek) aparece  mais especializado. A resposta à pergunta do Centauros é um bocado complicada, eu acho que um critério moderno para uma palavra ser lexicalizada e entrar no dicionário é análise de frequência das palavras em publicações e online. Ou seja, se uma palavra começa a ser muito usada tem de ser dicionarizada para os utilizadores terem acesso a uma definição. Como nerd/geek já são adjectivos/nomes establecidos no estrangeiro entram mais facilmente do que eg.[uber](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9631)

Comment: @Centaurus Quanto à nota que fazes de "inventar" palavras, o consenso em Portugal tem sido aproveitar o vocabulário técnico estrangeiro sem alteração, em geral [os franceses são indicados como um contra-exemplo](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-vocabulary/learn-some-french-computer-terms/) e quando lemos alguma coisa em francês parece que eles traduzem mais do que nós, afrancesando os estrangeirimos - o que leva a problemas de vocabulário acrescido embora homogeneíze a pronúncia.

Comment: @bad_coder  "inventar palavras" soa um pouco pejorativo. Eu escrevi "criar palavras" ou então traduzir.  Já aqui no Brasil, a tendência é incorporar os anglicismos conforme eles são apresentados com pronuncia adaptada ao pt-BR. Há uma invasão de tais palavras e eu acho que deveríamos cuidar melhor de nossa língua, cá por estas bandas.

Comment: @Centaurus foi lapso meu, a expressão popular em Portugal é sempre "inventar palavras" e foi assim que o meu cérebro leu. Acho que temos essa carga perjorativa -que se traduz numa resistência à mudança- como hábito cultural.

Comment: Eis o problema: nerdice funciona dentro do genio da língua; nerd, não porque o português não tem palavras que acabam assim. E é preciso então dizer: nerd*e* para poder dizê-la em português.

Answer (score -1):

O estatus das palavras no português brasileiro são as seguintes:

- nerd: estrangeirismo
- nerdice: neologismo

[Saiba a diferença](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/diferencas-entre-neologismo-estrangeirismo.htm).